# sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV how to retrieve all .best_params_

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, svm

```
svc_pipeline = make_pipeline(
    StandardScaler(), SVC(random_state=1)
)
pipe_svc_bag = BaggingClassifier(
    base_estimator=svc_pipeline, n_estimators=10, bootstrap=True, random_state=1
)
param_grid = [
    {'base_estimator__svc__kernel': ['linear', 'poly', 'rbf', 'sigmoid']},
    {'base_estimator__svc__C': np.linspace(0.1, 2, 20)}
]
svc_bag_grid = GridSearchCV(
    estimator=pipe_svc_bag, param_grid=param_grid, cv=10
)
svc_bag_grid.fit(X, y)
print(svc_bag_grid.best_params_)
```

I specified two parameters in `param_grid`, when I call `svc_bag_grid.best_params_` it only returns `{'base_estimator__svc__kernel': 'linear'}`, but I also want to know the best C value of `SVC()` I specified inside `param_grid`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

param_grid needs to be a dictionary, and each parameter is an element in it. Rather than a list of dictionaries as you have it...

```
param_grid = {'base_estimator__svc__C': np.linspace(0.1, 2, 20),
    'base_estimator__svc__kernel': ['linear', 'poly', 'rbf', 'sigmoid']}
```